# Save UIImage to photos album and then open Photos app

Tags: iphone

Currently I am saving a UIImage to the photos album using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum, which works fine.

Is there a way to then open the Photos app showing the just-saved photo? (I assume my app must close before opening Photos, which is fine.)

Simply opening the Photos app to the Saved Photos Album would be a not-quite-as-good alternative if the above isn't possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to open the photos app. But, as a workaround, you can open the album where you saved the photo using `UIImagePickerViewController`. Then, the user can click on the image and see it. That way, they won't even have to exit your application.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible using the SDK. If this is something you think is needed, you should [file an enhancement request](http://bugreporter.apple.com).